# Rename 2 files with the same name inside a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I have 2 folders an image folder and a txt folder and i want to rename the first image for example 1.png and the first txt is 1.txt and so on until they hit file length but in my case its 0.png 2.png and so on and 1.txt and 3.txt and so on , what i want is to make the image and the txt file equally named , here is my code :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')

const dir = __dirname + '/files/newFiles'
const fileNames = fs.readdirSync('files')

if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    if(!fs.existsSync(dir+'\\image')) fs.mkdirSync(dir+'\\image');
    if(!fs.existsSync(dir+'\\txt')) fs.mkdirSync(dir+'\\txt');
}

const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

const fileLength = fileNames.length ;

async function renameFiles() {
for(let i = 0 ; i < fileLength ; i++) { 
    const ext = path.extname(fileNames[i])
    if(ext === '.png') fs.copyFileSync( __dirname +"/files/" + fileNames[i], dir +'/image/' + i + ext);
    if(ext === '.txt') fs.copyFileSync( __dirname +"/files/" + fileNames[i], dir +'/txt/'+ i + ext);
        
    await timer(500);
}
}

renameFiles()
```

Comment: Create two variables `pngIndex` and `txtIndex`. Increment them inside their respective if statements and use in filenames to get individual numbering.

Comment: @Bqardi its working , u are a genius man totally forgot about this technique 